# Dynamic data is not sending to sendgrid template

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I have sendgrid email template in which I want to send dynamic data from my nodejs app but it is showing error.

This is how I am sending data:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY); 

const msg = {
    to: 'me.example18@gmail.com',
    from: 'exmple1@gmail.com',
    templateId:'d-8e322d7da4f44ca1afc76aefb3723444',
    personalizations: [
        {
            dynamic_template_data: {
                Sender_Name: 'Bookbudi',
                Sender_Address: '971/32 alwar gate',
                Sender_City: 'Ajmer',
                Sender_State:'Rajasthan',
                Sender_Zip:'305001'
            }  
        }
    ]   
};

sgMail.send(msg);
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong and how should I correct it.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: code:400,message:'bad request'

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is incorrect. See this example:

```
 const result = await this.sgMail.send({
            personalizations: [{
                to: this._to,
                dynamic_template_data: Object.assign({}, this._dynamic_template_data, {app: app}, {from: this._from})
            }],
            from: this._from,
            templateId: this._templateId,
        });
```

Try moving "to" to the personalizations array.